# Simulate user navigation with React Testing Library and React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I have a component that is meant to trigger when the user navigates away from a page. It wraps a formik form; if a user has unsaved changes, it attempts to save those changes as soon as the user attempts to navigate away. While the save is resolving, users will see a modal that says "saving..." If the save is successful, the user continues on to the next page. If it is unsuccessful, it displays a modal prompting them to either stay or move along. The component works fine, but I'm struggling to test it.

Component in question:

```
const AutoSaveUnsavedChangesGuard: React.FC<Props> = ({
  when,
  onLeave,
  children,
  ignoreRoutes = [],
  submitForm,
}) => {
  const { push } = useHistory();
  const { error, savingStatus } = useSavingStatusContext();
  const [nextLocation, setNextLocation] = React.useState<string>();
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showUnsavedChangesModal, setShowUnsavedChangesModal] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showSavingModal, setShowSavingModal] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleBlockNavigation = (nextLocation: Location) => {
    if (!!matchPath(nextLocation.pathname, ignoreRoutes)) {
      return true;
    }

    setNextLocation(nextLocation.pathname);
    setIsShowing(true);
    submitForm();
    return false;
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Proceed to next location when there has been a navigation attempt and client no longer blocks it
    if (!when && nextLocation) {
      push(nextLocation);
    }
  }, [when, nextLocation, push]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // If we have an error and we have triggered the Prompt, display the unsaved changes guard.
    setShowUnsavedChangesModal(!!error)
  }, [error]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setShowSavingModal(savingStatus=== SavingStatusType.SAVING)
  }, [savingStatus]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Prompt when={when} message={handleBlockNavigation}/>
      <UnsavedChangesModal
        show={showUnsavedChangesModal && isShowing}
        onLeave={() => {
          onLeave && onLeave();
        }}
        onStay={() => {
          setNextLocation(undefined);
        }}
        onHide={() => {
          setIsShowing(false);
          setShowUnsavedChangesModal(false);
        }}
      />
      <SavingModal show={showSavingModal && isShowing} />
      {children}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AutoSaveUnsavedChangesGuard;
```

I'm trying to test behavior with react-testing-library. I'd like to simulate a user navigating away (IE call the `message` method in the rendered component with a new location), but I am struggling to do so. We had a function like the one below when we tested using enzyme.

```
const changeRouteLocation = (nextLocation: Location, wrapper: ShallowWrapper) => {
    const prompt = wrapper.find(ReactRouter.Prompt);
    const onNavigate = prompt.props().message as (location: Location) => string | boolean;

    onNavigate(nextLocation);
  };
```

Unfortunately, this component uses `useEffect` hooks that don't play nice with enzyme, and I must test it using react-testing-library. How can I simulate a user attempting to navigate to a new location with react-testing-library?

Edit: Adding what I have for testing code per a request. This code does not produce the desired outcome, and I honestly didn't expect it to.

```
  const RenderingComponent = ({initialEntries})=>{
    return(
        <ThemeProvider>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={initialEntries}>
        <AutoSaveUnsavedChangesGuard {...defaults} />
        </MemoryRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }

 beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(ReactRouter, 'useHistory').mockReturnValue(makeHistory());
    useSavingStatusContextSpy = jest.spyOn(useAutoSaveContextModule, 'useSavingStatusContext')
  });
  
  it('should render default. It should not show any modals when there are no errors and the route has not changed.', async () => {
// Default rendering. Works fine, because it's not meant to display anything.
    const wrapper = render(
        <RenderingComponent initialEntries={['/initial-value']} />
    )
    expect(screen.queryByText('Saving...')).toBeNull();
    expect(screen.queryByText('Unsaved Changes')).toBeNull();
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  });

  it('should show the saving modal when the route location changes and saving status context is of type SAVING',()=>{
    useSavingStatusContextSpy.mockReturnValueOnce(makeAutoSaveContext({savingStatus: SavingStatusType.SAVING}))
    const {rerender, debug} = render(
       <RenderingComponent initialEntries={["initial-value"]} />
    )

    rerender(<RenderingComponent initialEntries={['/mock-value','/mock-some-new-value']} />)
// I had hoped that re-rendering with new values for initial entries would trigger a navigation event for the prompt to block. It did not work.

debug()

const savingModal = screen.getByText('Saving...');
expect(savingModal).toBeVisible();
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you share your `react-testing-library` code for testing this component? See [mcve].

Comment: That's the thing-- I'm at a sufficient loss that I don't have anything that's made progress.

All I've tried thus far is rendering it and re-rendering with new props to go into the router, but that hasn't triggered a navigation event. I'll edit it in, but I don't feel that it adds much by way of useful knowledge for my question.

Comment: I see. One of the keystones of using RTL is that the tests interact with the React components the same way users and other components would, via the rendered UI and props. In this case you may need to render a link or button and target that and issue a user click event to effect a navigation change action. Does this make sense?

Comment: I follow you. I actually just tested that a moment ago by adding a `NavLink` into the `MemoryRouter` component and simulating a click. Unfortunately, it does not appear to trigger the event as I'd hoped it might.

Comment: Yeah, what you are describing trying to test seems to me to be more of an integration test than a unit test. It might not be easy to with RTL alone and might need something more along the lines of puppeteer/cypress/selenium/etc.

Comment: Got it, finally! Turns out, I was mixing and matching code from `react-router` and `react-router-dom`. I eventually dug up the docs in RTL on testing react-router stuff, followed the example to a T, inserted my component, and got it to work. Thanks for the assist, guy! You da man!